# Bash - Terminal output listener

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

**Background**

This is going to sound weird, but I had a dream last night where I installed a piece of software that listened to the output on my terminal and ran a command/script if certain phrases were found.

**Question**

Does/could such software exist?

**Caveat**

The listener ran in the background during the course of an entire day. I never `grep`ed for any phrases.

Comment: Listens to a certain TTY or all TTY's - that are even created after the listener is started?

Comment: If you can engage it in a TTY, and use that same TTY for other purposes afterwards, that would do. Alternatively, you could have a TTY dedicated to this purpose, if it can listen to all other TTYs.

Comment: A named pipe can be used. I think it may be implemented.

Comment: ttylog may also be a tool utilised for this purpose

Comment: script -f /dev/pts/x is another tool to be used

Comment: I [use this kind of stuff](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/138342/how-to-read-write-to-tty-device) to debug embedded devices .. yes, this kind of stuff exists .. you could also use [`tee`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25645946/bash-redirect-output-to-tty-and-file) and some pipe redirection too ... there's also screen capture and keylogger programs that utilize this kind of stuff to capture and analyze all sorts of user input ..

Comment: @Alec have u tried Tera term? It s a terminal emulator in Windows. I used it to automate interactive programs. Check the macro command "wait". It lets u selectively feeds inputs upon receiving specific strings.